# Does Cycle.js (virtual-dom) support anything like React's refs or mithril's config property?

Tags: cyclejs, virtual-dom

In other words, is there any way to access a DOM element after it is rendered? Things like mouse focus, code highlighters, animations, how are they done in Cycle.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use standard `@cycle/dom` (for cycle@6) driver which uses virtual-dom there are hooks, which you can use as `on create` (`hook`) and `on destory` (`unhook`) events:
https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom/blob/master/docs/hooks.md

If you are using `cycle-snabbdom` it has even richer hooks mechanics: https://github.com/paldepind/snabbdom#hooks